# What is /bin/rbash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was learning about [Common shell programs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_01.html).

When I run `cat /etc/shells`, it shows:

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
```

What is `/bin/rbash` here? Is it used in scripting?

Comment: Which part of `man rbash` is unclear?

Comment: @StigHemmer. I didn't do it. `man rbash` also gives me detail information. Thanks.

Comment: Reading the man page should always be your first attempt to understand a tool. You should also read it on the machine where it appears to ensure you're reading about the correct version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell)

> The restricted shell is a Unix shell that restricts some of the
>   capabilities available to an interactive user session, or to a shell
>   script, running within it. It is intended to provide an additional
>   layer of security, but is insufficient to allow execution of entirely
>   untrusted software. A restricted mode operation is found in the
>   original Bourne shell[1] and its later counterpart bash,[2] and in the
>   Korn shell.[3] In some cases a restricted shell is used in conjunction
>   with a chroot jail, in a further attempt to limit access to the system
>   as a whole.

See [Soren A's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/868645/527764) for the limitations that apply to restricted shells.

You can run `bash` in restricted mode

```
bash -r
bash --restricted
```

On my system:

```
$ file /bin/rbash
/bin/rbash: symbolic link to bash
```

So if I run `/bin/rbash`, I am running `bash`

BUT

> It suffices to create a link named rbash pointing directly to bash.
>   Though this invokes bash directly, without the `-r` or `--restricted`
>   options, bash does recognize that it was invoked through rbash and it
>   does come up as a restricted shell.

As you can easily test:

```
zanna@monster:~$ rbash
zanna@monster:~$ cd playground
rbash: cd: restricted
```

Comment: Seems many restriction. Then how is it helpful? Does it use in scripting?

Comment: It could be set as default shell for a user you want to trap in a particular directory, for example @passa

Comment: @passa that's not scripting, and restricted shells are singularly useless for scripting. Since you know, or can determine, what actions are done in a script, there's no point to using a restricted shell for scripting.

Comment: @muru Okay. So this could be used for purpose that zanna said in her comment.

Comment: This is helpful to a system administrator because it can prevent other users from performing dangerous tasks. It is somewhat less useful to the end user.

Comment: I can't see a point of using it because of so many escape techniques

Answer (score 17):

rbash is a restricted (reduced capabillities) version of bash.
See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell

From the article:

> The following operations are not permitted in a restricted shell:
>
> ```
> changing directory
> specifying absolute pathnames or names containing a slash
> setting the PATH or SHELL variable
> redirection of output
> ```
>
> bash adds further restrictions, including:
>
> ```
> limitations on function definitions
> limitations on the use of slash-ed filenames in bash builtins
> ```
>
> Restrictions in the restricted Korn shell are much the same as those
>   in the restricted Bourne shell.